# CSS Calling and Declaring Classes

Tags: css, css-selectors

Okay, so I am slightly confused with declaring and calling a class in css. when I create a class it uses a "." but when I call it it doesn't, for example.

```
.smaller-image {
    width: 100px;
}

<a href="#"><img src="someimageurl.com" class="smaller-image" alt="some image 
text."></a>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is very hard to tell what you are aiming for. May you please state that clearly as a conclusion of your question?

Comment: Yes, they answered my question, but when declaring the class there is a period at the beginning, but not when you're actually calling the class. That is what confused me for a moment. Love stack overflow though and how helpful everyone is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS applies style to HTML elements using either their `class`, `id` or tag name (e.g. `body`).

When writing a CSS rule to apply to a `class`, you prefix the class name with `.`.

When writing a CSS rule to apply to an `id`, you prefix the id name with `#`. Note that an id should only be used by one element on a page, whereas a class can be used as often as you like.

Examples:

```css
div {} /* This is applied to all div elements */

.button {} /* This is applied to all elements with the `button` class */

#header {} /* This is applied to the element with the `header` id */

a.link {} /* This combines both the `a` tag and the `link` class */
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, that waas actually really helpful, so the div {} applies to all div elements, and I am sure just to separate specific div's you just give it an id,

Answer (score 1):

The preceding dot defines it as a *class* in CSS, as opposed for example to a *tag* like `div` (no prefix at all) or a hash for an *id* (`#something`). In HTML all that is not needed, since the attributes are `class` , `id` or no attribute.

Comment: Thank you, I am just used to actual coding, to where if I create a class or object or variable like, var myVar = 15, then I can just call it by saying like if (myVar = 15) { console.log("Your Number is " + myVar); else { console.log("Your Number is Not 15); } which is a very basic example, but I am not used to created a variable or class and calling it with a different name, even though its just a . at the beginning, it just threw me off a little

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, the class names are clearly class names because they are contained in the `class` attribute. They don't need anything else to make it clear they are class names.

In CSS, a selector can be made up of many things. IDs, element types, attribute names, attribute values -- and others! So you need something to make it clear that what you are using is a class name. The `.` character means "what comes next is a class name".

Answer (score 1):

The name HTML stands for Hyper Text Markup Language, and it describes the structure of web pages using markup elements that represented by tags. Each tag can hold attribute(s).

The class attribute specifies one or more class names for an HTML element.

CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheets and it describes how HTML elements are to be displayed on screen (or in other media).

In CSS, to select HTML elements with a specific class, we use period (.) character, followed by the name of the class.

Hope this clarify your mind, and enjoy coding!

Edit: in your example you use .com as source. You can't. 
Read here for images format and support:
 https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support

Comment: I know what HTML and CSS were, definitely didn't answer my question at all lol